# How to identify the type of data represented in the form of a String in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

For example, let th efunction be `typeIdentifier()`, therefore:

```
typeIdentifier('123') //Number
typeIdentifier('Hello') //String
typeIdentifier('2021-01-01T00:00:06+05:30') //Date
typeIdentifier(231) //Number
typeIdentifier(true) //Boolean
```

or say `'true'`, `'0xff'`, `'1e-10'`, `'0b101'`, `'/[a-z]/'` (regex?), `'[1]'` (array?), `'Infinity'`, `'NaN'`, `'null'`, `'123123123123123123n'`

Comment: `'123'` is a string no? Or better a number formatted as a string

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures ?

Comment: I believe, your main problem is to detect string-like numbers or string-like dates (the rest can be distinguished with `typeof`). So, you may pass those strings to `.isNaN()` to check for number or `new Date()` to find whether it looks like something, similar to *known* date formats.

Comment: What about strings such as `'true'`, `'0xff'`, `'1e-10'`, `'0b101'`, `'/[a-z]/'` (regex?), `'[1]'` (array?), `'Infinity'`, `'NaN'`, `'null'`, `'123123123123123123n'`, ...etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `typeof` and `JSON.parse` and a few other functions to determine a type. As you did not specify what should happen with a few other cases, I made some assumptions. It should not be hard to tailor it to your specific needs:

```js
function typeIdentifier(arg) {
    if (arg === null) return "null";
    if (Array.isArray(arg)) return "array";
    if (typeof arg !== "string") return typeof arg;
    try { // If string represents JSON, return the type of the parsed value
        arg = JSON.parse(arg);
        return typeIdentifier(arg);
    } catch {}
    if (!isNaN(arg)) return "number";
    if (!isNaN(new Date(arg).valueOf())) return "date";
    return "string";
}

let data = [
    '123',   // number
    'Hello', // string
    '2021-01-01T00:00:06+05:30', // date
    231,     //number
    true,    // boolean
    'true',  // boolean
    '1e-20', // number
    '0xff',  // number
    '0b101', // number
    'null',  // null
    '[1, 2]',// array
    '{}',    // object
];

for (let arg of data) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(arg), typeIdentifier(arg));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [typeof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof)

```
function typeIdentifier(x) {
    console.log(typeof x)
}
```

If you then run that function and give it a string, in the console you will see `string`, or `number` if it is a number etc...

You can add conditionals inside an do things like

```
typeof x === 'number' && // run some code
```

Also I'd recommend looking in to [TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/) - It's a superset of JavaScript used to check Types when writing code so you can catch errors and fix them beforehand.